# How many git branches should I have and am I merging them correctly?

Tags: git, heroku, git-branch

I have 3 branches master, develop and develop1 for my project. I work on develop1 and then when I am satisfied and ready to deploy I merge it to develop. Then I go to master and merge it with develop. Is this the correct process? If not what approach should I take. (I have intermediate develop branch just because if I mess something up in develop1 I can always go back to my last working code which is on develop branch.)

Comment: Branch names, in Git, are pretty much irrelevant. How many you should have and use, and what you should name them, is *entirely up to you*. There's no right answer, except whatever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly modify your workflow to use something like the Gitflow Workflow (see [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)). This would mean having a dev branch which is the current working version of the code and any new features you create should be created on a feature branch which is merged into dev when you are finished. When you want to do an official release you can merge dev into master and master will therefore have the current version that is released to the world.

I find this workflow very efficient and i highly recommend to us it or something similar.

Comment: Do you mean creating a new branch everytime I am working on a new feature? Does it not get messy when you have 20 features in future and will have a lot of branches.

Comment: When you want a new feature, you create a new feature branch and work on it until the feature is done. Then merge the feature branch into dev and delete the feature branch. This means that you will never have that many branches